# How do I prevent a copy of a grid's datasource from not getting changed when the grid's data changes?

Tags: c#, winforms, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, xtragrid

This is a C# Windows Forms project.  I have a grid on a form.  To get the data for the grid, I run a SQL procedure and store the results in a class.  I want to have a copy of that class so I know what the values were before the user changes them in the grid.  So I assign the class to another class.  Then I assign the first class as the grid's datasource.  However, after the change is made, both the original class and the copy have the same values.  How do I prevent this?

Here's is my code:

```
List<Unreceive> receivedItems = new List<Unreceive>();
List<Unreceive> listItems = mpBLL.GetMPItemsReceived();

receivedItems = listItems;
gcUnreceive.DataSource = listItems;
```

at this point, let's say receivedItems.quantity and listItems.quantity have a value of 100.

The user changes the data in the grid so the quantity is 50.  That triggers this code:

```
    private void gvUnreceive_CellValueChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView gridView = (DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView) sender;
      int index = gridView.GetDataSourceRowIndex(rowHandle);
      Unreceive selectedItem = listItems[index];
      Unreceive originalItem = receivedItems[index];

      int newQuantity = selectedItem.quantity;
      int originalQuantity = originalItem.quantity;
    }
```

At this point I want:
 newQuantity = 50;
 originalQuantity = 100;

But what I get is:
 newQuantity = 50;
 original Quantity = 50;

It's like I passed a variable by reference instead of by value, but I haven't passed it anywhere. How do I fix this so that the receivedItems class isn't effected by what happens to the listItems class or the datagrid?

Comment: Take a look at [Reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), [Value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) and [C# Concepts: Value vs Reference Types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx).

Comment: Also search about deep copy and shallow copy, for example take a look at [Difference between Shallow copy and Deep copy](http://net-informations.com/faq/net/shallow-deep-copy.htm) or [Shallow copy and Deep copy in C#](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shallow-copy-and-deep-copy-in-c-sharp/) or this [docs example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right that it seems "byRef"

receivedItems = listItems;
"object = object" would share the Pointer to where the data is not create a new pointer to a new data structure.

You were on the right track in creating a new list initially.
List receivedItems = new List();

You need to loop through your original list and create **new distinct list items** for the copy list - setting each property to the value of the master list.  This will give you two lists with separate memory storage.